# Problem with migration for renaming a column with foreign key

Tags: php, database, laravel

I want to rename a column in my database from `trainees_supervisor_id` to `person_supervisor_id` so I created a migration using `php artisan make:migration xxx`.

When I try to migrate it using command `php artisan migrate --path=/database/migrations/2019_07_19_121945_rename_trainees_supervisor_id_in_training_plan.php` I get an error (shown below) but such key exists in my database as you can see in the image 
ERROR:

```
 exists (SQL: alter table `training_plan` drop foreign key `training_plan_trainees_supervisor_id_foreign_foreign`)
```

migration:

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class ChangeFieldName extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('training_plan', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropForeign(['trainees_supervisor_id_foreign']);
            $table->renameColumn('trainees_supervisor_id', 'person_supervisor_id');
            $table->foreign('person_supervisor_id', 'person_supervisor_id_foreign')
                ->references('person_id')
                ->on('person');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('training_plan', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropForeign(['trainees_supervisor_id_foreign']);
            $table->renameColumn('trainees_supervisor_id', 'person_supervisor_id');
            $table->foreign('person_supervisor_id', 'person_supervisor_id_foreign')
                ->references('person_id')
                ->on('person');
        });
    }
}
```

Any idea why this migration doesn't want to go through?

Comment: Don't use an array as parameter, just use `$table->dropForeign('trainees_supervisor_id_foreign');` https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#indexes

Answer (score 0):

```
training_plan_trainees_supervisor_id_foreign_foreign
```

is not exist please remove foreign from your foreign key in code like this:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('training_plan', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropForeign(['trainees_supervisor_id']);
        $table->renameColumn('trainees_supervisor_id', 'person_supervisor_id');
        $table->foreign('person_supervisor_id', 'person_supervisor_id')
            ->references('person_id')
            ->on('person');
    });
}
```